# 415 error (null media type) when use jquery-file-upload in IE9

Tags: jquery, jsp

I use jquery-file-upload in my project and it works well in chrome. 
But in IE, it return (415 - Unsupported Media Type) (INFO: The system cannot find any method in the ...OwnFileAPI class that consumes **null media type**. Verify that a method exists that consumes the  media type specified.)

Here is the code snippet :

JQuery :

```
$('#file-upload-form').fileupload({
  sequentialUploads : true,
  add : function(e, data) {
    ...
    data.submit();
  },
  submit : function(e, data) {
   ...
  },
  progress : function(e, data) {
    ...
  },
  fail : function(e, data) {
    ...
  },
  done : function(e, data) {
    ...
  }
});
```

JSP :

```
<form class="row-fluid" id="file-upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<c:url value="/resources/api/user/files/own/csrfToken/"></c:url><wm:csrfToken/>" target="files-upload-target">
    <span class="btn fileinput-button" id="file-upload-btn">
        <strong><fmt:message key="files.action.upload"/></strong>
        <input type="file" id="file-uploader" name="ownFile" tabIndex="-1">
    </span>

</form>
```

JAVA :

```
@CSRF
@Path(PathConst.OWN_FILE_API_CSRFTOKEN)
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String upload(@PathParam("csrfToken") String csrfToken, InMultiPart inMP) {
    ......
}
```

Please provide some pointers to resolve this issue...THX!

Comment: please do post the answer for this or check whether my suggestion is correct

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct, then you might submitting the file with the help of the ajax request. While submitting the file through ajax request you have to assign the request headers like content-type and content-disposition headers and you also have to send the content of the file as the boundary separated value as how the normal form submission works.

You can also refer to [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)